# jquery div refresh works once

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to refresh a divs content by using .load. This works, **but only once**. I think it has something to do with the actual  link being inside the div code that is reloaded, but I don't know how to proceed to fix it.

### index.php

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myrefresh').click(function(){
$('#mycontent').load('content.php', function() {
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mycontent"><?PHP include("content.php");?></div>
</body>
```

### content.php

```
<?PHP
//content to update variables from database here...this is working

//display the variables
echo "<table width=\"253\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"5\" bordercolor=\"#000000\" bgcolor=\"#000000\">".
    "<tr>".
    "<td><a><div id=\"myrefresh\"><img src=\"Images/BJ.png\" width=\"243\" height=\"50\" /></div></a></td>".
  "</tr>".
"<tr>".
    "<td bgcolor=\"242424\"><table width=\"243\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">".
      "<tr>".
        "<td width=\"16\"><img src=\"Images/T1.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"24\" /></td>".
        "<td><div align=\"right\" class=\"style3\">".$variable1."</div></td>".
      "</tr>". //etc more echo code here
```

I think the issue is

```
<a><div id=\"myrefresh\"><img src=\"Images/BJ.png\" width=\"243\" height=\"50\" /> </div></a>
```

being refreshed and then not being able to run again, but like I said I am lost as to how to fix it.

Comment: The posted answers are correct.  To actually understand why, see the event delegation section of the documentation for `on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks James, the solution presented does in fact work, I will look at the link you provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the links are dynamic, you'll need to bind the event handler to the parent element, as you can't bind events to elements that are'nt there, and will be added with ajax in the future.

```
$('#mycontent').on('click', '#myrefresh', function() {
    $('#mycontent').load('content.php');
});
```

Comment: ...and to explain WHY this is the right answer: You're `#myrefresh` is bound to on page load. After a refresh, the container is emptied (`#myrefresh` removed along with bindings) so, although you may have a new `#myrefresh` element, there is no longer a `click` binding associated to it. Using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) fixes this by binding _now_ and _later_.

Comment: @BradChristie By `live` I think you mean "Using event delegation with `on`".

Comment: @JamesMontagne: yes, corrected. I'm still getting over the whole deprecation thing and still have a couple of older projects I work on/support.

Comment: Also, +1 for using the deepest possible static dom element instead of `document` in the selector.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! This now works as needed. Can't upvote yet...if I could I would.

Comment: @Jon Just be sure to mark the best answer as the accepted answer. (green checkmark next to the question)

Answer (score 2):

You return the new button. So the "old" HTML object is removed, this means the old handler does not exists anymore. Try this:

```
$('body').on("click", "#myrefresh", function(){
   $('#mycontent').load('content.php', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The myrefresh div is being removed/recreated from the DOM on reload. You need to use event delegation with `.on()` method in jQuery as such:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myrefresh', function () { ... });
```